# How to keep colour in clothes?

Tags: cleaning, clothing, personal-care

I've noticed that in jeans, especially new ones, the colour tends to leak from them. Are there any ways to mitigate this? I've heard of washing them in cold water, turning them inside out, and adding a cup of white vinegar. Should these be done each time to keep the original color intact?

Comment: I'm posting this as a comment cause I don't remember details, but my mom used to rinse the clothing in fresh/cold water with **salt** as soon as we got them back home from the store, we never experienced "lost of intensity" in any of our clothing. She would only do this with jeans and clothing of certain fabric and color.

Answer (score 1):

New denim clothing they may have "loose dye" in them, so yeah wash them several times in cold water to wash the loose dye out, from then on you can wash them with your other clothes, but I'd recommend washing them with dark colours and turning them inside out stops them rubbing against the other clothes and rubbing off the dye. That's all I can suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Washing in cold water should work. I wash all delicate or color bleeding clothing in cold water. Please make sure to also separate those from other clothing/light colored jeans so in case it bleeds, it doesn't bleed the color on other stuff.

Answer (score 0):

If you're convinced the vinegar rinse works, yes, you're supposed to use it every time, in the last rinse, and it has to be white vinegar. I never found it made any difference though - if your jeans are indigo dyed, then they 'bleed' every time you wash them, and when they're new, the colour bleeds or transfers onto pale furniture and carpets if you sit on them.

Definitely turn them inside out every time before washing, always do up the buttons and zipper, use cold water for the whole wash unless they're particularly dirty, do use a liquid wash intended for dark clothing, don't dry them in direct sunlight - this helps to keep the colour for longer. If your jeans aren't fashionably 'patchy', with paler areas for aesthetic effect, you can buy an indigo jeans dye and re dye them when they get particularly faded.

http://www.amazon.co.uk/Dylon-350-Machine-Dye-Salt/dp/B00UJGOJYI/ref=dp_ob_title_kitchen

The results from using this aren't quite the same as brand new jeans though.

Answer (score 0):

Use Color Catchers. I've only ever done my own laundry once but no colors ran or faded. If that isn't an accomplishment, I don't know what is.